# OpenLayers: How do I make a TileLayer start from origin?

Tags: tiles, openlayers

I'm using `OpenLayers` to display a large image using a `TileLayer` with an `XYZ` source and a pixel projection. On top of that image I'm supposed to show some bounding boxes that have coordinates depending on an origin that's on the upper left side.

For starters I wanted to make the image show on screen starting from the origin (which in OL's case is lower left). However, it does show the image, but the lower part of it is still under the view. Using the `MousePositionControl` I can clearly see that the image does not start from [0,0].

Here's the code I'm using:

```js
const mapExtent: Extent = [0, 0, ...map.getSize()];
const projection = new Projection({
  code: "pixels",
  units: "pixels",
  extent: mapExtent,
});
const center = getCenter(mapExtent);
const view = new View({
  projection,
  center,
  resolution: 1,
});
map.setView(view);
```

And here's the `TileLayer` I'm using:

```js
const layer = new TileLayer({
  source: new XYZ({
  url: "<MY_ENDPOINT>",
  tileLoadFunction: (tile, url) => {
    getTile(url, (base64) => {
      ((tile as ImageTile).getImage() as HTMLImageElement).src = base64;
    });
  },
  wrapX: false,
  projection: map.getView().getProjection(),
}),
```

I have tried adding an extent to the layer of the size of the map itself, but it didn't work. Other than that I really am stuck here. I have checked the documentation and not found any clues that would be relevant to my situation.

I should note that I don't really know the size of the image beforehand. I just want it to start rendering it (tile - [0,0]) from the origin [0,0].

I'm new to this so if you could explain my mistake to me I would be very appreciative.

Edit:
Added screenshots of an example image. The lower left side of the first image has coordinates [0,0]. But when I go down, you can see the the lower left edge of the image is not at [0,0].
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm using `React` for the UI in case you're wondering about the weird code :)

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: please use the [edit] link to update your question directly rather than in the comments. Can you also include a screen shot to help us understand what's going on

Comment: @IanTurton I have updated the question. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: By default `ol/source/XYZ` creates a tile grid which uses the top left of the projection extent as origin.  To override that you will need to specify a `tileGrid` option with your own constructed with `ol/tilegrid/TileGrid` which has the `origin` option set.

Comment: @Mike Thank you for the response! OL documentation is never clear about origin for each layer type. `tileGrid` makes it pretty clear, but other than that... What about `VectorLayer`? Why is origin in the lower left everywhere, but for `TileLayer`s it's on the upper left? I don't see the logic here. 

Anyway, if you make your comment an answer I'll mark it as such. Thanks again!

Comment: For instance, now I have bounding boxes that have upper left origins. I have no idea what the origin for `VectorLayer` is. Assuming it's the lower left side, I'm going to have to use `addCoordinateTransforms` to align my bounding boxes with the tiles right? It's poorly documented.

Comment: Tile grids are the same for any mapping application, XYZ starts at top left https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/canvas-tiles.html and TMS at bottom left.  That is not related to projection axes.